# Maximal value for a function with a bounded n'th derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, boundary-value-problem

I have a function $f$ whose $n$'th derivative is Lipschitz-continuous with constant $1$, and satisfies $f(0)=f'(0)=\dots=f^{(n)}(0)=0$, and  $f'(1)=f''(1)=\dots = f^{(n)}(1)=0$. I'm interested in finding the largest possible value that can be attained for $f(1)$.

For example, when $n=1$, the largest value $f(1)$ can attain is $1/4$ using the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2} x^2, & x\leq \frac{1}{2}, \\\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2} (x^2 - 1)^2, & x>\frac{1}{2}.
\end{cases}
$$ 
For n=2 I think the best value is 1/32, but I don't have a proof for that.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: It can be that i am wrongly digesting the given data. For $n=1$ let us consider the spline function $s:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ which is $x\to x^2/2$ on $[0,1-\epsilon]$ and constant on $[1-\epsilon,1]$. Which is the property which is ok for the posted $f$, but fails for $s$?

Comment: @dan_fulea: the gradient of the function in your example does not satisfy the requirement that f'(1)=0 - I need all derivatives up to the n'th derivative in the endpoints to be 0.

Comment: The function $s$ above is constant and equal to $(1-\epsilon)^2/2$ on $[1-\epsilon,1]$, so its derivative is vanishing in $1$.

Comment: Right, sorry: the first derivative of $s$ is not Lipschitz continuous ($s$ is continuous, but its first derivative is not).